# How can I prevent Heroku corrupting / changing my .bin file when uploaded?

Tags: node.js, heroku, git-lfs, bin

I am trying to upload a node.js project to Heroku, it includes .bin files that represent weightings for an image segmentation model. When these files are uploaded to heroku they are being changed. I am able to verify this by printing the checksum and comparing it the checksum value locally.

I had this problem initially when pushing my .bin files to github but was able to fix it by adding this to my .gitattributes file:

```
*.bin filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.bin binary
```

It seems that this fix doesn't apply when the files get pushed to Heroku using `git push heroku main --no-verify`

Any ideas?